# How to call a web service from within a webservice

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I am trying to create a web service which is a consumer to another webservice. Here is the layout.

I developed a Java class and created a webservice out of it.

Then I used Eclipse tools to generate a client side stub and other files.

I packed these files in a jar and used it in another project. I tested the files in the jar I was able to access the first webservice.

Now I created another webservices from the project that I tested the first one from.

Now when I write a client to the second web service it seemingly is not able to find the stubs for the first one. gives me the following error

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: com/cats/patient/PatientDataStub
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:512)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:370)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:416)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:228)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:163)
    at com.esps.patient.PatientDataESPSStub.getPatientByID(PatientDataESPSStub.java:186)
    at com.esps.patient.ESPSTestClient.main(ESPSTestClient.java:22)
```

I have incorporated all the jars in all the projects.

Comment: Are both of these web services living on the same application server instance?  i.e. in the same tomcat war.

Comment: Not very clear to me - You mean to say Client talking to WebService1 and WebService1 talks to WebService2. Who is not able to find the stub for WebService2? Is it WebService1 or you getting this in Client?

Comment: Nathan, yes both the webservices are on the same tomcat servcer instance but under different contexts.

Bhushan, the client is not able to locate the stub for WS2 not WS1. You got rest of it right.

Comment: client ----> web service 1 ----> web service 2
has ws1 stub jars

Comment: client ------------> web service 1 -----------> web service 2
both cient and ws1 project have ws2 stub classes jars

Comment: If client is not talking to WS2 then why to put the WS2 stub in client? You need stubs of WS1 in client.

Comment: Yeah, here we ask questions but not funny questions

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the exception client have found the stub of WS1. The exception fault happened when reading response.

Try [tcpmon](https://tcpmon.dev.java.net/) to see what was the request and response. Before tcpmon you can check in WS1 if its recieving any requests from client by putting some debug info.

Comment: the client talks to WS1 and WS1 talks to WS2. I have packed the stub jars of WS2 in the client but still no go. I am using the stubs of the WS2 in WS1 not the client, just FYI.

Thanks, but the situation still prevails

Comment: Dude you really need correctly put your question, so have created so much confusion. Read your comment again, you say client talks to WS1 but you put stubs of WS2. If you will not put stub of WS1 in client how will it get the stub?

Comment: sorry about the confusion I shall try explaining again 
          consumes                         consumes
client ---------------------->WS1 --------------------------->WS2
has ws2 &             has ws2 stub jars
ws1 stub jars

Comment: sorry again this thing does not preserve formatting...again

the client consumes WS1 and WS1 consumes WS2.. WS1 contains the jars for WS1 stubs and client has jars for both WS2 and WS1 stubs..

this is the scenario. Hope it is clearer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring frawe work then I suggest you to use RestTemplate to call another Webservice from another Webservice.